# Why I can't access gem on github in my app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

**I can't access my gem on github in my app.**

In directory of "check" local repository :

1. `my@pc:/check$` **bundle install / update**
2. `my@pc:/check$` **bundle info exam**

   - exam (0.1.0 e21d9f9)
     Summary: Just example
     Homepage: https://github.com/
     Path: /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@check/bundler/gems/exam-e21d9f936578
3. `my@pc:/check$` **ruby runner.rb**

   `Traceback (most recent call last):`
       `2: from runner.rb:1:in '<main>'`
       `1: from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in 'require'`
   `/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in **'require': cannot load such file -- exam (LoadError)**`
4. **gem which exam**

`ERROR:  Can't find Ruby library file or shared library exam`
During process "bundle install" path has been added to $LOAD_PATH but then when I open $LOAD_PATH over irb , this path is absent there

```
**gem env**
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.1.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.6.3 (2019-04-16 patchlevel 62) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@check
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/pc/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@check/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/pc/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@check
     - /home/pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@check/bin
     - /home/pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@global/bin
     - /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin
     - /usr/share/rvm/bin`
```

Comment: Just put a `gemspec` line in the Gemfile and list deps in the gemspec file

Comment: It doesn't help. The issue with LoadError

Comment: @Orion Edwards  help, please

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to activate Bundler so that it can add your exam gem to the load path. You can either execute your code with [`bundle exec`](https://bundler.io/v2.0/man/bundle-exec.1.html):

```
$ bundle exec ruby runner.rb
Hola from gem
```

or add [`require 'bundler/setup'`](https://bundler.io/v2.0/guides/bundler_setup.html#setting-up-your-application-to-use-bundler) to runner.rb before 'exam' is loaded:

```
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'exam'

# Console.new.run
Game.greeting
```

```
ruby runner.rb
Hola from gem
```

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot.